# Combine Google Places and Google Geocoding APIs

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Here is my situation: I use Google Places Autocomplete to help the user choosing a destination. I want then to use the data of the chosen destination (geocode type in Google Places)
The thing is that, through Google Places Details (with reference token), the details provided are not optimal, compared with the one give by Google Maps Geocoding API.
For example, Google Maps API provides a viewport and a bound box for almost every destination, whereas Google Places Details never provides any bound box and gives a viewport only some times.

So I wonder if there is a way to pass the destiantion from Google Places Autocomplete to Google Geocoding API. Could we use the reference token or the unique id as a junction?
Of course we could use the "formatted_address" but it doesn't insure unicity and integrity of the data so I don't think it's a good idea.
I'm sure there must be a gateway between Google Places and Google Geocoding APIs but I don't think it's documented.
So if someone has some experience about that, I'd be glad to hear it.

Thanks